# Do magnetic field lines actually cancel?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Typically when explaining why parallel conducting wires attract, it is said that their magnetic fields cancel out (in the case of same direction current) and hence produces an attraction force due to the lack of magnetic field there:

[image]

However I was considering another scenario where this doesn't seem to work. Consider a metal plate going into a magnetic field as shown below:
[image]

The induced eddy current produces an outward magnetic field. This would 'cancel' out with the external magnetic field and hence attract. But that can't be right! We know that the coil gets slowed not accelerated upon entry!

So my question is, why is the magnetic field not cancelling out and attracting here?

Comment: You should not think about attracting currents in terms of canceling fields. You should think f the field of wire 1 and how it exerts a force on wire 2, and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

It is not  because of the cancellation  of the magnetic line, but because of the direction of the magnetic line. The magnetic lines in the opposite direction attract each other and repels each other in the same direction. The two wires attract, because the magnetic lines between the wires are in opposite directions (attached) and the magnetic lines on both sides are in the same direction(repelled), but  obviously  the attraction is greater than the repulsion force , so the wires are generally attractive. I am referring your figure 1.